# dynamically adding kivy widgets

Tags: kivy

I can add a new widget, but it something isn't connecting correctly. The canvas seems like its in the wrong coordinate system.

My .py

```
class Ship(Widget):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(Ship, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.vel = 10

class Game(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.ship = Ship()
       self.add_widget(self.ship)
       self.ship.center = self.center
```

My .kv

```
<Ship>
   size: 50, 50
   canvas:
       Color:
           rgb: 0, 0, 1
       Rectangle:
           size: self.size
           pos: self.pos
<Game>
   canvas.before:
       Color:
           rgb: 0, 0, 0
       Rectangle:
           size: self.size
           pos: self.pos
```

This creates the image:
[image]

I would expect the blue box to be dead center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you assign the center position, layout has not yet been calculated. Every widget starts off at size 100, 100 by default, and your `Ship` is being positioned correctly in the center of that 100, 100 area. If you want the `Ship` to remain centered, you need to bind the properties:

```
class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.ship = Ship()
       self.add_widget(self.ship)
       self.bind(center=self.ship.setter('center'))
```